# Deployment of php directory requests

Tags: php, wordpress, deployment, readdir, scandir

I've had a look around and I can't find a neat solution;

Trying to use readdir() or scandir() to get the names of files in a folder

The problem is this function (as I understand it) queries the root folder of the server and doesn't take web addresses, so therefore the path I need to pass to this function has to change from when I am developing on my localhost, to when I deploy it onto a live web server.

Is there a better function to use or something I am missing so that I can write one bit of code that works for finding files in a folder, regardless of whether it is deployed locally or on a web server? Do I have to turn to Java?

hope everyone gets what I'm on about, cheers in advance!

Comment: Just make it `__DIR__`-relative to the current script, or utilize the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` if that's at least consistent across localhost and live server.

Comment: your awesome, think I should be able to make it work using `__DIR__`